# Trying to match bootsrap card heights when on a desktop computer

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have been looking for a solution and nothing I have found on any sites have been working for me. I am wanting the card heights to match when on a large screen and fit under each other on small screens. Currently it all works except the cards don't match heights and it looks awful. I could also use a recommendation on how to change the heights to make them larger without empty space in the card

```html
              <div class="card-group row d-flex ">
               <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12">
                <div class="card bg-dark text-white" >
             <img class="card-img img-fluid" 
          src="../website/image/lightbulb.jpg" alt="Card image">
             <div class="card-img-overlay">
               <h5 class="card-title"></h5>
               <p class="card-text"></p>
               <button class=' btn-primary'></button>
              </div>
             </div>
              </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12">
              <div class="card bg-dark text-white" >
                <img class="card-img img-fluid" 
          src="../website/image/stress1.jpg" alt="Card image">
                <div class="card-img-overlay">
                  <h5 class="card-title"></h5>
                  <p class="card-text"></p>
                  <button class=' btn-primary'></button>
                </div>
               </div>
              </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12">
              <div class="card bg-dark text-white" >
                <img class="card-img img-fluid" 
          src="../website/image/blackhole.jpg" alt="Card image">
                <div class="card-img-overlay">
                  <h5 class="card-title"></h5>
                  <p class="card-text"></p>
                  <button class=' btn-primary'></button>
                </div>
               </div>
              </div>
             </div>
           </div>
       </div>
```

Wanting cards to match height regardless of photo and I want to be able to make all the cards bigger without overflow

Comment: Since you're using overlay cards there will be empty space in the cards depending on the image height. is this what you want?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    html {
      font-family: Lato, 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
    }
    
    h5 {
      font-size: 1.28571429em;
      font-weight: 700;
      line-height: 1.2857em;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .card {
      font-size: 1em;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 0;
      border: none;
      border-radius: .28571429rem;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #d4d4d5, 0 0 0 1px #d4d4d5;
    }
    
    .card-block {
      font-size: 1em;
      position: relative;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 1em;
      border: none;
      border-top: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, .1);
      box-shadow: none;
    }
    
    .card-img-top {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
    
    .card-title {
      font-size: 1.28571429em;
      font-weight: 700;
      line-height: 1.2857em;
    }
    
    .card-text {
      clear: both;
      margin-top: .5em;
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .68);
    }
    
    .card-footer {
      font-size: 1em;
      position: static;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      max-width: 100%;
      padding: .75em 1em;
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
      border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .05) !important;
      background: #fff;
    }
    
    .card-inverse .btn {
      border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    }
    
    .profile {
      position: absolute;
      top: -12px;
      display: inline-block;
      overflow: hidden;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      width: 25px;
      height: 25px;
      margin: 0;
      border: 1px solid #fff;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
    
    .profile-avatar {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
    
    .profile-inline {
      position: relative;
      top: 0;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .profile-inline~.card-title {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-left: 4px;
      vertical-align: top;
    }
    
    .text-bold {
      font-weight: 700;
    }
    
    .meta {
      font-size: 1em;
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    }
    
    .meta a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    }
    
    .meta a:hover {
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .87);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mt-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://picsum.photos/200/150/?random">
          <div class="card-block">
            <h5 class="text-bold">Tawshif Ahsan Khan</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mt-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://picsum.photos/200/150/?random
    ">
          <div class="card-block">
            <h4 class="card-title">Tawshif Ahsan Khan</h4>
            <div class="meta">
              <a href="#">Friends</a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-text">
              Tawshif is a web designer living in Bangladesh.
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <span class="float-right">Joined in 2013</span>
            <span><i class=""></i>75 Friends</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mt-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://picsum.photos/200/150/?random
    ">
          <p class="card-block">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam velit quisquam veniam excepturi temporibus inventore corporis dicta sit culpa veritatis placeat earum, dolorum asperiores, delectus dolore voluptatibus, at magnam nobis!
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mt-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://picsum.photos/200/150/?random
    ">
          <div class="card-block">
            <figure class="profile">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/150/?random" class="profile-avatar" alt="">
            </figure>
            <h4 class="card-title mt-3">Tawshif Ahsan Khan</h4>
            <div class="meta">
              <a>Friends</a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-text">
              Tawshif is a web designer living in Bangladesh.
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <small>Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary float-right btn-sm">show</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mb-5">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mt-4">
        <div class="card card-inverse card-primary ">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://picsum.photos/200/150/?random">
          <blockquote class="card-blockquote p-3">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat.</p>
            <footer>
              <small>
                              Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
                            </small>
            </footer>
          </blockquote>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mt-4">
        <div class="card card-inverse card-info">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://picsum.photos/200/150/?random">
          <div class="card-block">
            <figure class="profile">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/150/?random" class="profile-avatar" alt="">
            </figure>
            <h4 class="card-title mt-3">Tawshif Ahsan Khan</h4>
            <div class="meta card-text">
              <a>Friends</a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-text">
              Tawshif is a web designer living in Bangladesh.
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <small>Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
            <button class="btn btn-info float-right btn-sm">Follow</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mt-4">
        <div class="card card-inverse card-info">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://picsum.photos/200/150/?random">
          <div class="card-block">
            <figure class="profile profile-inline">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/150/?random" class="profile-avatar" alt="">
            </figure>
            <h4 class="card-title">Tawshif Ahsan Khan</h4>
            <div class="card-text">
              Tawshif is a web designer living in Bangladesh.
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <small>Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
            <button class="btn btn-info float-right btn-sm">Follow</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mt-4">
        <div class="card card-inverse card-info">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://picsum.photos/200/150/?random">
          <div class="card-block">
            <figure class="profile profile-inline">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/150/?random" class="profile-avatar" alt="">
            </figure>
            <h4 class="card-title">Tawshif Ahsan Khan</h4>
            <div class="card-text">
              Tawshif is a web designer living in Bangladesh.
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Follow</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Card image is just a wanton background through the card-img-overlay tag. In your case I would create a css background for each card. Then the heights in the desktop view are correct.

```css
.card-background {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12 d-flex">
      <div class="card card-background" style="background-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/img_avatar1.png);">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Nick</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
            sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
            duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
          <button class='btn btn-primary'>Button</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12 d-flex">
      <div class="card card-background" style="background-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/img_avatar4.png);">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Peter</h5>
          <p class="card-text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
          </p>
          <button class='btn btn-primary'>Button</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12 d-flex">
      <div class="card card-background" style="background-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/img_avatar6.png);">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Michele</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
            sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
          <button class='btn btn-primary'>Button</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: All the images now have a margin that fits the largest image but the images havent filled the space and the images still dont match

Comment: Hi @Roughcaster, now I understand your issue. I have revised my answer.